# How to find four points from the binary image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image like following, I want to find four coordinate (corners) from this image.

I have tried with below code:

```
# dilate thresholded image - merges top/bottom 
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=3)
# Finding contours for the thresholded image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[image]

First, I dilated the image so that it fill up the scatter portion and tried to find out contours from there. But it gives me wrong output.
What I can do this for finding out four corner coordinates?

Comment: try to find the 4 sides (longest lines or approxPolyDp?) and use the intersection points.

Comment: @Micka, It doesn't give expected result. :(

Comment: that statement is insufficient. you always have to say what did *you* do, what *did happen*, and what you *expected* to happen instead. -- I would recommend using `minAreaRect`

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque see the answer of user2640045 which is basically same as my approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found your points by putting a regression line threw each of your sides and taking their interception points.

First I import stuff and find the contour points with open cv.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
from sympy import solve, symbols
import itertools

img = cv2.imread('ZrSqG.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

threshold, binarized_img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binarized_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = (contours[1].reshape(-1,2)).T
```

Now I get a few of the top most, left most etc. points and put a line threw them. Then I calculate their interceptions and plot it all.

```
def interpolate_function(x,y):
    line = interpolate(x,y)
    return lambda x: x*line.slope+line.intercept 

def interpolate(x,y):
    idx = np.argsort(x)
    line = linregress(x[idx], y[idx])
    return line

def interception(line1, line2):
    x = symbols('x')
    x = solve(x*line1.slope+line1.intercept-(x*line2.slope+line2.intercept))[0]
    return (x,x*line1[0]+line1[1])

idx_x = np.argsort(contours[0])
idx_y = np.argsort(contours[1])
left = [contours[0][idx_x[:30]], contours[1][idx_x[:30]]]
right = contours[0][idx_x[-10:]], contours[1][idx_x[-10:]]
top = contours[0][idx_y[:10]], contours[1][idx_y[:10]]
bottom = contours[0][idx_y[-30:]], contours[1][idx_y[-30:]]

contour_functions = [interpolate_function(*left), interpolate_function(*right),interpolate_function(*top), interpolate_function(*bottom)]
contour_function_eqs = [[interpolate(*left), interpolate(*right)],
    [interpolate(*top), interpolate(*bottom)]]

for f in contour_functions:
    t = np.linspace(0, img.shape[1], 10**4)
    t = t[(0 < f(t)) & (f(t) < img.shape[0])]
    plt.plot(t,f(t))
    
itersections = np.array([interception(line1, line2) 
    for line1, line2 in itertools.product(contour_function_eqs[0], contour_function_eqs[1])])
plt.scatter(itersections[:,0], itersections[:,1])
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

And I get
[image]

Or if you prefer to follow the bottom left part you just reduce the points in the bottom by replacing

```
bottom = contours[0][idx_y[-30:]], contours[1][idx_y[-30:]]
```

with

```
bottom = contours[0][idx_y[-10:]], contours[1][idx_y[-10:]]
```

and you get
[image]

Comment: `contours = (contours[1].reshape(-1,2)).T`, Here, `contours[1]` maybe different, how can I choice this index number?

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque Your example had only one contour. If you have multiple ones maybe plot the different contours in different colors and go from there?

Comment: If I use this `contours = (contours[2].reshape(-1,2)).T`, then what would it happen? I think It can't capture the all points. Is this code applicable for only this image?

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque I doubt that it only works for this picture. I am having a hard time debugging your problem without having access to your other picture though. Maybe you just open a new question with it?

Comment: `contours = (contours[1].reshape(-1,2)).T`, I have doubt about this line. What will happen If I use `contours = (contours[0].reshape(-1,2)).T`,  or `contours = (contours[2].reshape(-1,2)).T` etc.? Is there any generalize form?

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque that depends on contours[2], contours[0]. If it's the points on the contour that your wishing to complete then it should do what you want. You might have to adjust the amount of points you base it on though. I suggest you scatter plot the left right, top etc. points and see if they reassemble the top bottom etc.